# Laravel-5 Deleting a folder or file does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Good;
use App\Image;

class testpost extends Controller
{
    //
    public function execute(Request $request){

            $file = "/Users/local/Desktop/111/2.png";
            //$folder = "/Users/local/Desktop/111";
            //unlink($file);
            dd(Storage::delete($file));
            //$status_delete_file=Storage::deleteDirectory($folder);

    }
}
```

I'm trying delete file "/Users/local/Desktop/111/2.png". And Storage does not remove this file or folder 111. No errors, always returns "false". Tried to remove file through standard function PHP "unlink"

```
unlink($file)
```

All well removes!

### Help me please.

Laravel 5.4
PHP 7.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Laravel `Storage` Facade used for managing file in `$root` directory of your Laravel filesystem disk.

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    ....

],
```

Please refer to this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#configuration). If your `disk` is `local` then `$root` directory will be `storage/app`, or if it `public` then `$root` directory will be `storage/app/public`. All operation: `create`, `move`, `delete` will do inside the defined `$root` directory.

By the way Laravel use `league/flysystem` package to handle `Storage` operation. You can see in the package source [code](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Local.php#L252) what is `Storage::delete()` actualy doing.

```
// flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function delete($path)
{
    $location = $this->applyPathPrefix($path);
    return unlink($location);
}
```

The delete function actually call `unlink` function. But adding directory prefix before do the operation.

So example: if a you want to delete file `uploads/image.jpg` in your `public` disk storage, you just need to call

```
Storage::delete('uploads/image.jpg')
```

Comment: I made the code for local storage.
`
$good = Good::find($request->id);
      $directory = storage_path('app/public/i/upload/good/'.$request->id."/");
      dump($directory);
      dd(Storage::deleteDirectory($directory));
`
Deletion does not work.
I apologize, I can not label the code.